# Flask - Allowing the First item in the dropdown to populate the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, flask, dropdown

I am experimenting with Flask and was trying to create a page where I can start typing in a text box and have that narrow down what appears in the dropdown menu. I have that down but I'm running into trouble with actually selecting the first item in the dropdown list and having that populate the text box, so far I can only populate it using the other options. Example python and template code below. Any help is greatly appreciated.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample list of cities
cities = [
    'New York',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Chicago',
    'Houston',
    'Phoenix',
    'Philadelphia',
    'San Antonio',
    'San Diego',
    'Dallas',
    'San Jose'
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/suggest_cities', methods=['POST'])
def suggest_cities():
    search_term = request.form['searchTerm']
    suggestions = [city for city in cities if search_term.lower() in city.lower()]
    return jsonify({'suggestions': suggestions})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Suggest Cities</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cityInput').on('input', function() {
          var searchTerm = $(this).val();
          if (searchTerm.length >= 2) {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/suggest_cities',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {searchTerm: searchTerm},
              success: function(response) {
                var suggestions = response.suggestions;
                var options = suggestions.map(function(city) {
                  return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>';
                }).join('');
                $('#citySelect').html(options);
                $('#citySelect').show();
              },
              error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
              }
            });
          } else {
            $('#citySelect').empty();
            $('#citySelect').hide();
          }
        });
        $('#citySelect').change(function() {
          var selectedCity = $(this).val();
          $('#cityInput').val(selectedCity);
          $('#citySelect').hide();
        });
        $('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var cityInput = $('#cityInput').val();
          var cityOptions = $('#citySelect option').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }).get();
          if (cityOptions.includes(cityInput)) {
            alert('You selected ' + cityInput + '!');
          } else {
            alert('Please select a city from the drop-down menu.');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="cityForm">
      <label for="cityInput">Enter a city:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cityInput" name="cityInput">
      <select id="citySelect" style="display: none;"></select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question should be tagged for JS/jquery etc, not python/flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UX here is a bit awkward. Rather than the flow you're currently attempting:

1. user types into input
2. user selects from dropdown
3. changing the dropdown changes the original filter input
4. submit form using original filter input as user's selection.

I'd propose the simpler and less surprising:

1. user types into input
2. user (optionally) selects from dropdown if they're not happy with the top result
3. submit form using the current dropdown option as the user's selection.

This is better for the user because it's impossible to make a "bad" selection and their filter is never blasted away from an unexpected copy from another field. Less clicking/typing/selecting is involved--they can narrow everything down using the filter input and simply press Enter to accept whatever's at the top of the dropdown. From our perspective, the code is easier.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Suggest Cities</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function getSuggestions() {
        var searchTerm = $('#cityInput').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/suggest_cities',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {searchTerm: searchTerm},
          success: function(response) {
            var suggestions = response.suggestions;
            var options = suggestions.map(function(city, i) {
              return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>';
            }).join('');
            $('#citySelect').html(options);
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        getSuggestions();

        $('#cityInput').on('input', getSuggestions);

        $('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var selected = $('#citySelect').val();

          if (selected) {
            alert('You selected ' + selected + '!');
          }
          else {
            alert('No cities match your query.');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="cityForm">
      <label for="cityInput">Enter a city:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cityInput" name="cityInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="citySelect"></select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

A few other considerations:

- If you have a lot of cities and don't want to hit the server if the user has only typed 1 or 2 characters, that's fine, but I'd add some messaging like "please type 2 more characters to search" so that the user isn't confused when they hit a key and nothing happens.

  A better approach might be to limit the responses to the first 10 or so, debounce inputs and/or throttle the number of requests. I avoided these because they may be premature optimizations.
- If the list is as small as in your example, or even if it's only a few hundred items, you might as well serve it up front, right in the template, then do all the filtering on the front-end. Faster for the user, less work for your server. But I'm not sure what your actual use case is, so I've played along with your design more or less.
- It's a little odd that the dropdown appears and disappears. I'd prefer to see it the whole time. It's easy to implement if you need to hide/show it though, so I left that out.
- CSS names are usually `kebab-case`, but I kept them `camelCase` to not divert from your original code too much.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot! I'm pretty new when it comes to flask and working with jquery. I had a simple form where i had no issue with taking POST data and saving it to a CSV, I seem to be having trouble submitting this form data. Can you help me to get started? I can't seem to grab the data and do anything with it on the python side.

Comment: thanks, I did so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176746/trying-to-submit-jquery-form-data-to-flask