# Trying to submit jquery form data to flask

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I recently received assistance on a jquery / flask form element and as I am completely new to this I am having trouble with figuring out how to submit the form data so I can process it in the python so I can save it or otherwise process the data. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Template File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Suggest Cities</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function getSuggestions() {
        var searchTerm = $('#cityInput').val();
        $.ajax({
          url: '/suggest_cities',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {searchTerm: searchTerm},
          success: function(response) {
            var suggestions = response.suggestions;
            var options = suggestions.map(function(city, i) {
              return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>';
            }).join('');
            $('#citySelect').html(options);
          },
          error: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
      }

      $(document).ready(function() {
        getSuggestions();

        $('#cityInput').on('input', getSuggestions);

        $('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var selected = $('#citySelect').val();

          if (selected) {
            alert('You selected ' + selected + '!');
          }
          else {
            alert('No cities match your query.');
          }
          $.ajax({
            url: '/process_form',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#cityForm').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="cityForm">
      <label for="cityInput">Enter a city:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cityInput" name="cityInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="citySelect"></select>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

flask python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample list of cities
cities = [
    'New York',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Chicago',
    'Houston',
    'Phoenix',
    'Philadelphia',
    'San Antonio',
    'San Diego',
    'Dallas',
    'San Jose'
]

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/suggest_cities', methods=['POST'])
def suggest_cities():
    search_term = request.form['searchTerm']
    suggestions = [city for city in cities if search_term.lower() in city.lower()]
    return jsonify({'suggestions': suggestions})
    
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        return f'Thank you for submitting the city, {city}!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I'd add a route for processing the form and make an ajax request to it, similar to what you're doing with suggestions.

Comment: something like.... @app.route('/process_form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        return f'Thank you for submitting the city, {city}!'

Comment: Yep, although you probably don't need a GET method, just POST. Try adding it to the code and sending a request to it using `$.ajax`.

Comment: getting close when I submit I get error 400: "POST /process_form HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: Can you [edit] to show your latest code? Thanks

Comment: @app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        print(city)
        return f'Thank you for submitting the city, {city}!'

Comment: Please [edit] your post with the code. It's hard to read as a comment. Where is your ajax request that's POSTing to this endpoint? I would return JSON like your other route, not text, which is hard for a client to consume.

Comment: done sorry for the delay!

Comment: No problem, but I think you forgot your ajax request to that endpoint. `$('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {` needs to have an `$.ajax({` like the other event handler, otherwise the endpoint won't do anything for you.

Comment: added but still no joy :/ still get "POST /process_form HTTP/1.1" 400 -

Comment: Thanks, it's reproducible now. Your `<select>` tag is missing a `name`. Try `<select id="citySelect" name="citySelect"></select>`.

Comment: actually appear to have broken my code if you're interested in having a look I made [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76270789/broke-flask-app-trying-to-invoke-process-form-function-to-submit-data) regarding the issue