# Broke Flask App, trying to invoke "process_form" function to submit data

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I've been attempting to implement a flask app to manage taking data from a form and inserting it into a csv file. I did have this working but I seem to have broken it as I've been adding "suggest_cities" and "suggest_counties" functionality for searchable dropdown lists but I'm not quite sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm new to both Flask and ajax.

jinja / ajax code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Suggest Cities</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        function getSuggestions() {
          var searchTerm = $('#cityInput').val();
    if (searchTerm.length >= 3) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/suggest_cities',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { searchTerm: searchTerm },
        success: function(response) {
          var suggestions = response.suggestions;
          var options = suggestions.map(function(city, i) {
            return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>';
          }).join('');
          $('#citySelect').html(options);
          console.log(options);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
        }

        function getCountySuggestions() {
          var searchTermcount = $('#countyInput').val();
          if (searchTermcount.length >= 3) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/suggest_counties',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { searchTermcount: searchTermcount },
            success: function(response) {
              var csuggestions = response.csuggestions;
              var coptions = csuggestions.map(function(county, i) {
                return '<option value="' + county + '">' + county + '</option>';
              }).join('');
              $('#countySelect').html(coptions);
              console.log(coptions);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
          }
        }

        getSuggestions();
        getCountySuggestions();

        $('#cityInput').on('input', getSuggestions);
        $('#countyInput').on('input', getCountySuggestions);

        $('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var selected = $('#citySelect').val();

          if (selected) {
            alert('You selected ' + selected + '!');
          } else {
            alert('No cities match your query.');
          }

          $.ajax({
            url: '/process_form',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#cityForm').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log("ajax invoked: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Intake Form:</h1>
    <form method="POST" id="cityForm">
      <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
      <br>
      <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" required>
      <br>
      <label for="cityInput">Enter a city (type until you see your city or type "other"):</label>
      <input type="text" id="cityInput" name="cityInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="citySelect" name="citySelect"></select>
      <br>
      <label for="state">State:</label>
      <!--<input type="text" name="state" required>-->
      <select name="state">
        {% for state in list_of_states %}
           <option value={{state}}>{{state}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="county">County:</label>
      <!--<input type="text" name="county" required>-->
      <input type="text" id="countyInput" name="countyInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="countySelect" name="countySelect"></select>
      <br>
      <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="zip_code" required>
      <br>
      <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone_number">
      <br>
      <label for="is_cell_phone">Is this a cell phone number?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="is_cell_phone">
      <br>
      <label for="discord_username">Discord Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="discord_username" required>
      <br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Python code:

```
import csv
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample list of cities
"""
cities = [
    ' ',
    'New York',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Chicago',
    'Houston',
    'Phoenix',
    'Philadelphia',
    'San Antonio',
    'San Diego',
    'Dallas',
    'San Jose',
    'Lake Elsinore'
]
print(cities)
"""

list_of_states = [
    'AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA','CO','CT','DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','IA','ID','IL','IN','KS','KY','LA','MA','MD','ME','MI','MN','MO','MS','MT','NC','ND','NE','NH','NJ','NM','NV','NY','OH','OK','OR','PA','PR','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VA','VT','WA','WI','WV','WY'
    ]
cities = [ ]
with open('city.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rawlist = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n'))
    cities = [x for b in rawlist for x in b] #list comprehension
#print(cities)

counties = [ ]
with open('county.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rawlist = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n'))
    counties = [x for b in rawlist for x in b] #list comprehension
    #print(counties)

udate = subprocess.run(['date'], capture_output=True, text=True)
date_time_output = udate.stdout.strip()
print("Date and Time:", date_time_output)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        city = request.form['city']
        state = request.form['state']
        county = request.form['county']
        zip_code = request.form['zip_code']
        phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        is_cell_phone = request.form.get('is_cell_phone')
        discord_username = request.form['discord_username']

        with open('responses.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([first_name, last_name, city, state, county, zip_code, phone_number, is_cell_phone, discord_username])

        return f'Thank you for submitting the form, {first_name} {last_name}!'
    return render_template('index.html', list_of_states = list_of_states)

@app.route('/suggest_cities', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def suggest_cities():
    search_term = request.form['searchTerm']
    suggestions = [city for city in cities if search_term.lower() in city.lower()]
    return jsonify({'suggestions': suggestions})

@app.route('/suggest_counties', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def suggest_counties():
    csearch_term = request.form['searchTermcount']
    csuggestions = [county for county in counties if csearch_term.lower() in county.lower()]
    print(" suggest counties")
    return jsonify({'csuggestions': csuggestions})

@app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        print(city)
#        return f'Thank you for submitting the city, {city}!' + render_template('index.html')
#    return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        #state = request.form['state']
        state = request.form['state']
        county = request.form['county']
        zip_code = request.form['zip_code']
        phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        is_cell_phone = request.form.get('is_cell_phone')
        discord_username = request.form['discord_username']
        print("Date and Time:", date_time_output)
        with open('responses.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([first_name, last_name, city, state, county, zip_code, phone_number, is_cell_phone, discord_username])
            f'Thank you for submitting the form, {first_name} {last_name}!'
        return render_template('index.html')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: Broken it in what way? Is there an error (if so, which)? Could you share your actual/expected output? Thanks.

Comment: sorry I thought I'd answered my own question didn't realize I'd not actually done so until you commented. I actually am just about done with this app and I've greatly appreciated you help my final question is about a redirect after filling out the form successfully that is [not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76284568/flask-form-not-redirecting) your help on this last bit would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just forgotten to change the name of the source data for the post when I switched from a textbox to a dropdown list.