# Flask Form Not Redirecting

Tags: python, templates, flask, redirect, jinja2

I have a working flask form that I'm trying to have redirect to a "thank you" page after it is successfully filled out. For some reason it won't redirect successfully and I can't seem to see why. Any help in figuring this out would be greatly appreciated. The Redirect is being handled from the python side of the app.

Python code

```
import csv
import subprocess
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample list of cities
"""
cities = [
    ' ',
    'New York',
    'Los Angeles',
    'Chicago',
    'Houston',
    'Phoenix',
    'Philadelphia',
    'San Antonio',
    'San Diego',
    'Dallas',
    'San Jose',
    'Lake Elsinore'
]
print(cities)
"""

list_of_states = [
    'AK','AL','AR','AZ','CA','CO','CT','DC','DE','FL','GA','HI','IA','ID','IL','IN','KS','KY','LA','MA','MD','ME','MI','MN','MO','MS','MT','NC','ND','NE','NH','NJ','NM','NV','NY','OH','OK','OR','PA','PR','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VA','VT','WA','WI','WV','WY'
    ]
cities = [ ]
with open('city.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rawlist = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n'))
    cities = [x for b in rawlist for x in b] #list comprehension
#print(cities)

counties = [ ]
with open('county.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    rawlist = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n'))
    counties = [x for b in rawlist for x in b] #list comprehension
    #print(counties)

udate = subprocess.run(['date'], capture_output=True, text=True)
date_time_output = udate.stdout.strip()
print("Date and Time:", date_time_output)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        city = request.form['city']
        state = request.form['state']
        county = request.form['county']
        zip_code = request.form['zip_code']
        phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        is_cell_phone = request.form.get('is_cell_phone')
        discord_username = request.form['discord_username']

        with open('responses.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([first_name, last_name, city, state, county, zip_code, phone_number, is_cell_phone, discord_username])

        return f'Thank you for submitting the form, {first_name} {last_name}!'
    return render_template('index.html', list_of_states = list_of_states)

@app.route('/suggest_cities', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def suggest_cities():
    search_term = request.form['searchTerm']
    suggestions = [city for city in cities if search_term.lower() in city.lower()]
    return jsonify({'suggestions': suggestions})

@app.route('/suggest_counties', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def suggest_counties():
    csearch_term = request.form['searchTermcount']
    csuggestions = [county for county in counties if csearch_term.lower() in county.lower()]
    print(" suggest counties")
    return jsonify({'csuggestions': csuggestions})
"""
@app.route('/thankyou', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def thank_you():
    return "<p>Hello, World from \
                redirected page.!</p>"
"""
@app.route('/process_form', methods=['POST'])
def process_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        print(city)
#        return f'Thank you for submitting the city, {city}!' + render_template('index.html')
#    return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.form['first_name']
        last_name = request.form['last_name']
        city = request.form['citySelect']
        #state = request.form['state']
        state = request.form['state']
        county = request.form['countySelect']
        zip_code = request.form['zip_code']
        phone_number = request.form['phone_number']
        is_cell_phone = request.form.get('is_cell_phone')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        discord_username = request.form['discord_username']
        print("Date and Time:", date_time_output)
        with open('responses.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([date_time_output,first_name, last_name, city, state, county, zip_code, phone_number, is_cell_phone, email,discord_username])
            return redirect(url_for('thank_you'))

@app.route('/thankyou')
def thank_you():
    return render_template('thankyou.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

index.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Intake Form</title>
      <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    form {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    label {
      display: block;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    input[type="text"],
    select {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 5px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;

    input[type="submit"] {
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-appearance: none; /* Added property */
  }
    }
  </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        function getSuggestions() {
          var searchTerm = $('#cityInput').val();
    if (searchTerm.length >= 3) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '/suggest_cities',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { searchTerm: searchTerm },
        success: function(response) {
          var suggestions = response.suggestions;
          var options = suggestions.map(function(city, i) {
            return '<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>';
          }).join('');
          $('#citySelect').html(options);
          console.log(options);
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
        }

        function getCountySuggestions() {
          var searchTermcount = $('#countyInput').val();
          if (searchTermcount.length >= 3) {
          $.ajax({
            url: '/suggest_counties',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { searchTermcount: searchTermcount },
            success: function(response) {
              var csuggestions = response.csuggestions;
              var coptions = csuggestions.map(function(county, i) {
                return '<option value="' + county + '">' + county + '</option>';
              }).join('');
              $('#countySelect').html(coptions);
              console.log(coptions);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
          }
        }

        getSuggestions();
        getCountySuggestions();

        $('#cityInput').on('input', getSuggestions);
        $('#countyInput').on('input', getCountySuggestions);

        $('#cityForm').submit(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var selected = $('#citySelect').val();

          /*if (selected) {
            alert('You selected ' + selected + '!');
          } else {
            alert('No cities match your query.');
          }*/
          console.log("Before AJAX request");

          $.ajax({
            url: '/process_form',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#cityForm').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              console.log("ajax invoked: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Test Intake Form:</h1>
    <form method="POST" id="cityForm">
      <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" required>
      <br>
      <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name">
      <br>
      <label for="cityInput">Enter a city (type until you see your city or type "other"):</label>
      <input type="text" id="cityInput" name="cityInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="citySelect" name="citySelect"></select>
      <br>
      <label for="state">State:</label>
      <!--<input type="text" name="state" required>-->
      <select name="state">
        {% for state in list_of_states %}
           <option value={{state}}>{{state}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
      <br>
      <label for="county">County:</label>
      <!--<input type="text" name="county" required>-->
      <input type="text" id="countyInput" name="countyInput" autocomplete="off">
      <select id="countySelect" name="countySelect" required></select>
      <br>
      <label for="zip_code">Zip Code:</label>
      <input type="text" name="zip_code" required>
      <br>
      <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone_number">
      <br>
      <label for="is_cell_phone">Is this a cell phone number?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="is_cell_phone">
      <br>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email">
      <br>
      <label for="discord_username">Discord Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="discord_username">
      <br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

thankyou.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Thank You!</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Thank You!</h1>
  <p>Your form has been submitted successfully.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the `thank_you` route commented out purposely?

Comment: afraid I'm not seeing what you mean about the route being commented out

Comment: oh, i didn't see the second one. sorry.

Comment: is your file tree correct? maybe it just can't find the file.

Comment: @cyberghost indexl.html and thankyou.html are in the templates folder. the app.py file is in the directory just above that, the root directory for the project.

Comment: then try doing an `app.thank_you` redirect. i have not tested this, but by looking at one off my own working apps, it seems like it could work.

Comment: app.thank_you? can you elaborate? do you mean calling return redirect(url_for('thank_you')) ?

Comment: I added a redirect call in the app.py file. in process_form() right after the call to write to the csv file.        ` code`with open('responses.csv', 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([date_time_output,first_name, last_name, city, state, county, zip_code, phone_number, is_cell_phone, email,discord_username])
            return redirect(url_for('thank_you')) `code`

Answer (score 0):

the return in the POST request will send the HTML page as a POST response.
A way to handle this would be to handle redirection from the client side.

You can replace `return redirect(url_for('thank_you'))` with something like `return {'status': 'success'}`

then in the callback function of the post request, you can set

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/process_form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#cityForm').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        if (response['status'] == 'success'){
            window.location.href = "/thankyou";
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log("ajax invoked: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Seemingly not doing the trick sadly not redirecting.

Comment: That's weird it worked on my system. I even faked-filled the data in `city.csv` and `county.csv` to check whether it works or not.

Comment: Weird....which browser were you using?

Comment: I use firefox usually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if it was an issue with differences in the environment between myself and other comments who said the answer just before this one worked but what worked for me was slightly different:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/process_form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#cityForm').serialize(),
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.href = "/thankyou";
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log("ajax invoked: "+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```